# Is it "a 5% discount", or "5% discount"

Tags: indefinite-article

I had a discussion with a colleague about this today:

He thinks it's: As 'company' partner, I get 5% discount

I think it's: As 'company' partner, I get a 5% discount

Who is correct and why?

Comment: I think it should be *"As **a** 'company' partner, I get **a** 5% discount."* Both *partner* and *discount* (as nouns) are countable.

Comment: I'm okay with "As company partner, I get a 5% discount." We can sometimes omit the article when talking about positions in a corporate heirarchy. Examples: _As upper management, we get assigned parking places_. Or, [_As Company Partner and Account Director, he leads strategy and product development_](http://www.snowflakecreative.co.uk/blog/seo-in-2014-the-year-cheap-tricks-dont-work/#sthash.nB5XP3wO.dpuf). I think the article is the safer way to go, but I wouldn't call it "wrong"; it depends on if "company partner" can stand on its own as a role.

Comment: In this case, 5% is an adjective modifying the direct object discount.  You can also say "I get 5% off" which is less formal.  Implied is "5% off of everything."  In this case, the article shouldn't be there as there isn't a direct object.  (Perhaps a better grammarian than I am can weigh in with a precise explanation of how "5% off" relates to the verb.)

Comment: @j.r. If "company partner" is a title, then yes. If it's a generic description, then it needs an article. "As Director of Accounting, he ..." versus, "As an accountant, he ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically incorrect!

As described by Damkerng, the nouns *partner* and *discount* are countable nouns and thus will take an article.

In addition, putting the word *company* in inverted commas may bring some complexity to this easy-to-understand statement.

> *As a company partner, I get a 5% discount.*

If you want to emphasize on you being a partner, you may stress the phrase *company partner* than just *company*.

Please note that the word [*'discount'* is also an uncountable noun.](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/discount)

Comment: As I said in my other comment, I wouldn't label the omission of the first article a grammatical mistake. (Moreover, the question is really asking more about the second article anyway.) But I agree that it's **a** 5% discount.

Comment: I believe that putting the word *company* inside apostrophes was intended to indicate that the actual company name was said there, but the questioner did not wish to use that actual name as part of this question.

Comment: You're right Hellion. I tried to put accolades around the word company, but StackExchange didn't let me.